# Problemas con selenium chromedriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, navegador-web, chromedriver

Soy nueva en esto del testing automation. Tengo un script para ejecutar con selenium, el problema esta en que al tratar de ejecutarlo, intenta abrir el browser y me da este mensaje en eclipse: ***ChromeDriver was started successfully***. Sin embargo, el browser no abre y automaticamente me arroja este error en eclipse: ***Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 92
Current browser version is 95.0.4638.69 with binary path C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe.***
Me parece que hay incompatibilidad con la version del browser de chrome que estoy usando (version 95). De ser ese el problema, debo volver a la version 92 de chrome? Y como haria para volver? O hay otra solucion? Ya intente usar el driver de firefox pero me da otro error.
Este es el script:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        

    introducir el código aquí
        //Estos primeros dos pasos es para poder abrir el Browser
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\May.Pul\\eclipse-workspace\\json\\src\\chromedriver\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.demoblaze.com/index.html");
        System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
        
        Datos d = new Datos();
        String nombre = d.obtenerUsuario();
        String contraseña = d.obtenerClave();
        String usuario2 = d.obtenerUsuario2();
        String pais = d.obtenerPais();
        String provincia = d.obtenerProvincia();
        String tarjeta = d.obtenerTarjeta();
        String mes = d.obtenerMes();
        String año = d.obtenerAño();
        System.out.println("El nombre del usuario es: " + nombre);
        System.out.println("No deberia decir la contraseña, pero es... :" + contraseña);
        System.out.println("El nombre del usuario que realizo la compra es: " + usuario2);
        System.out.println("Pais de origen :" + pais);
        System.out.println("Provincia: " + provincia);
        System.out.println("Numero de tarjeta: " + tarjeta);
        System.out.println("Mes de nacimiento: " + mes);
        System.out.println("Año de nacimiento : " + año);
        
        
        
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='login2']")).click();  
        Thread.sleep(500);
        driver.findElement(By.id("loginusername")).sendKeys(nombre);
        Thread.sleep(500);
        driver.findElement(By.id("loginpassword")).sendKeys(contraseña);
        Thread.sleep(500);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\'logInModal\']/div/div/div[3]/button[2]")).click();
        Thread.sleep(700);
        
        
        driver.findElement(By.linkText("Monitors")).click();
        Thread.sleep(500);
        driver.findElement(By.linkText("Apple monitor 24")).click();
        Thread.sleep(500);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"tbodyid\"]/div[2]/div/a")).click();
        //driver.findElement(By.linkText("Add to cart")).click();
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"nava\"]/img")).click();
        Thread.sleep(500);
        
        
        driver.findElement(By.linkText("Laptops")).click();
        Thread.sleep(500);
        driver.findElement(By.linkText("Sony vaio i5")).click();
        Thread.sleep(500);
        driver.findElement(By.linkText("Add to cart")).click();
        Thread.sleep(900);
        driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"nava\"]/img")).click();
        Thread.sleep(500);
        
        
        driver.findElement(By.linkText("Laptops")).click();
        Thread.sleep(500);
        driver.findElement(By.linkText("Sony vaio i7")).click();
        Thread.sleep(500);
        driver.findElement(By.linkText("Add to cart")).click();
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"nava\"]/img")).click();;
        Thread.sleep(500);
        
        
        driver.findElement(By.linkText("Phones")).click();
        Thread.sleep(500);
        driver.findElement(By.linkText("Samsung galaxy s6")).click();
        Thread.sleep(900);
        driver.findElement(By.linkText("Add to cart")).click();
        Thread.sleep(900);
        driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
        Thread.sleep(500);
        driver.findElement(By.id("cartur")).click();
        Thread.sleep(900);
        
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"page-wrapper\"]/div/div[2]/button")).click();
        Thread.sleep(500);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\'name\']")).sendKeys(usuario2);
        Thread.sleep(500);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\'country\']")).sendKeys(pais);
        Thread.sleep(500);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\'city\']")).sendKeys(provincia);
        Thread.sleep(500);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\'card\']")).sendKeys(tarjeta);
        Thread.sleep(500);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\'month\']")).sendKeys(mes);
        Thread.sleep(500);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\'year\']")).sendKeys(año);
        Thread.sleep(900);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\'orderModal\']/div/div/div[3]/button[2]")).click();
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".confirm.btn.btn-lg.btn-primary")).click();
        Thread.sleep(900);
        driver.findElement(By.id("logout2")).click();
        
        
        
        driver.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

el error se debe a que la version del controlador es distinta a su navegador, lo cual ocasiona que falle.

Recomiendo utilizar una libreria que seria la siguiente: https://github.com/bonigarcia/webdrivermanager

Lo que hace la libreria es quitarnos esa dependencia de tener el driver X en nuestro proyecto, pero su mejor funcion es descargar el driver con la version X en nuestra PC, quitando la dependencia de tener un driver absoluto y ahora tendriamos uno dinamico.

En consecuencia nos ofrece muchas ventajas y sirve para cuando queramos ejecutar en distintos entornos.